# Algorithm to remove words in corpus with small occurrence

Tags: java, algorithm, cpu-word

I have a large (+/- 300,000 lines) dataset of text fragments that contain some noisy elements. With noisy I mean words of slang, type errors, etc… I wish to filter out these noisy elements to have a more clean dataset.

I read some papers that propose to filter these out by keeping track of the occurrence of each word. By setting a treshold (eg. less than 20) we can assume these words are noise and thus can safely be removed from the corpus.

Maybe there are some libraries or algorithms that do this in a fast and efficient way. Ofcourse I tried it myself first but this is EXTREMELY slow!

So to summarize, I am looking for an algorithm that can filter out words, in a fast and efficient way, that occur less than a particular treshold. Maybe I add a small example:

```
This is just an example of whaat I wish to acccomplish.
```

The words 'whaat' and 'acccomplish' are misspelled and thus likely to occur less often (If we assume to live in a perfect world and typos are rare …). I wish to end up with

```
This is just an example of I wish to.
```

Thanks!

PS: If possible, I'd like to have an algorithm in Java (or pseudo-code so I can write it myself)

Comment: I don't really like your approach. There are plenty of rare but perfectly valid words that will be lost.  If you want to remove misspelt words, then spell check it.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: 1) construct a 2D array with number of rows equal to number of lines in the dataset.
2) read in line by line, add each word to a HashMap<String,Object> where String is the word, Object contains number of occurrences and a list of indexes (col, row) to find where this word occurs in the whole dataset.
3) I convert the line to a StringArray and add it to the 2D array as a row.
4) I sort the HashMap based on occurrences
5) For each word that has occurrences <= treshold, I take the (col, row) values and remove those
6) Read out the 2D array

Comment: @tom, in all the research papers I read about the thing I wish to accomplish, they suggest the same thing. They simply remove words that occur less than a particular treshold. This does not affect the results what so ever.

Comment: Be careful here. In normal English text, a large portion of legitimate words are hapaxes; they occur once in the entire corpus. And yet, those words are meaningful. They're often the subject of a sentence, or synonyms of other words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are over complicating it with the approach suggested in comments.

You can do it with 2 passes on the data:

1. Build a histogram: `Map<String,Integer>` that counts number of occurances
2. For each word, print it to the new 'clean' file if and only if `map.get(word) > THRESHOLD`

As a side note, if any - I think a fixed threshold approach is not the best choice, I personally would filter words that occure less than `MEAN-3*STD` where `MEAN` is the average number of words, and `STD` is the [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation). (3 standard deviations mean you are catching words that are approximately out of the expected normal distribution with probability of ~99%). You can 'play' with the constant factor and find what best suits your needs.